# List Out of Stock products last in WooCommerce Shortcodes

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Using this code to have products listed as "out of stock" listed last on Shop page but it doesn't change the order of the Woocommerce shortcodes.  Looking specifically for [product_category] shortcode to have "out of stock" products listed last.

```
 * Sorts the Woocommerce Archive product query to push out of stock products to the end 
 */
function _nok_order_by_stock_status( $posts_clauses, $query ) {

    // only change query on WooCommerce loops
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && ( is_product_category() || is_product_tag() || is_product_taxonomy() || is_shop() ) ) {
        global $wpdb;

        $posts_clauses['join'] .= 
        " LEFT JOIN ( 
            SELECT post_id, meta_id, meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta 
            WHERE meta_key = '_stock_status' AND meta_value <> '' 
        ) istockstatus ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = istockstatus.post_id) ";

        $posts_clauses['orderby'] = 
        " CASE istockstatus.meta_value WHEN 
            'outofstock' THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
        END ASC, " . $posts_clauses['orderby'];
    }

    return $posts_clauses;
}
add_filter( 'posts_clauses', '_nok_order_by_stock_status', 2000, 2 );
```